# How to reload profile files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am creating a script that I will put in `/etc/profile.d/namescript.sh`.  What it does is to add time to the `history` command.  The script is already done, but for my change to be executed I have to close the session.

I know the `source` command, and if I use it to reload the profiles outside the script it works, but if I put it inside the script it does not.

**My code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
   
FECHA_HORA="%d/%b/%Y %H:%M"
RUTA="/etc/profile.d"
PROOT="/etc/profile"
PUSER="$HOME/.profile"

if [[ ${UID} -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "Debes ejecutar el script con permisos de admistrador: sudo ${0}"
  exit 1
fi

cat <<EOF> ${RUTA}/timeHistory.sh
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="${FECHA_HORA} " 
EOF

exec bash "$PROOT" && exec bash "$PUSER"

exit 0
```

I have tried with `exec` and with `source` inside the script, and I can not get it to work, it only works when I close session.  That is why I need to reload the profile files.

Comment: Every process has its own environment. Each bash script is a new process unless run with `source`. Changes to the environment of one process have no effect on others.

Comment: Thanks for answering @stark, so what I want to do can be done, or can't it be done?

Comment: `profile.d` scripts aren't _supposed_ to be executed as subprocesses. The only correct way to invoke them is to source them.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you mean, the scripts that are put in `profile.d` are executed every time a user logs into the system, that's why I want to know how I can reload them using my script without logging out.